# Persisting Google Drive Session Data across University networks

Tags: python, windows, oauth, enterprise, google-drive-api

This seems to be an issue I've been seeing multiple people having issues with and has yet to be solved effectively. How can one maintain Google Drive at an enterprise level?

I'm working as a student programmer for my University and they just switched to Google Apps for Education and want to use Google Drive to allow students access to campus computer data anywhere.

Our campus system is called Labnet and it boots a fresh copy of Windows 7 using iSCSI and a logical volume manager. Every time students boot up a box, its the exact same fresh new PC smell. Because of this, the oAuth key google drive adds to the registry is blown away at reboot as is the drive folder and app data folder, all which like being on the C drive.

We built a wrapper for first time users to set up Drive on campus which redirects the default install location to the network drive and copies the app Data folder containing the sync_config.db and snapshot.db files to a network backup and exports the drive key to the network drive. At login, we have a script check for the backups, restore them all to C:\users\admin\appdata\local\drive, and import the oAuth token into the registry.

In theory, it works fine. In practice, its so so. The setup works fine in one lab where all the machines run the exact same hardware and are booting the same image file. When we try the importing the keys and appdata to a lab running slightly different hardware and software, we get `Error -2146893813 CryptUnprotectData, 'Key not valid for use in specified state'.` or `invalid data`.

I didn't think the oAuth was in anyway tied to the hardware or software of the machine, but it seems like it is.

Does anyone know of a way to persist this data in such a fashion that would allow users to access data without having to constantly setup drive at login?

I'll attach the full code here. It's a more than standard code block, So here's a link.

`GoogleDriveLabnetConfig.py` is the custom wrapper that changes the default Drive location to the H: drive.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fb27936jmm87w0l/GoogleDriveLabnetConfig.py

`MUNGoogleDriveDaemon.py` is a wrapper that copies the user's Appdata back and forth between C: and H: and actually launches Google Drive. We don't allow users to launch Google Drive independantly of this daemon because the snapshots won't be backed up.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z32t3bjluwl0wf5/MUNGoogleDriveDaemon.py

If anyone can help solve this, feel free to reuse the code in your own setups.

Edit: It might be possible to check the hardware and software of each computer at start-up and import a key generated for a specific hardware/software pairing, but that would result in users having to renter credentials every time they change labs and if we change the image, again in old labs. Not a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

A long shot, but try checking the system time on the machines. Oauth requires that all clients and servers have synchronised time.